# Python automatic pc restart

Tags: python, automation

hello all I have writen a .pyw script to automatically restart my computer if I have been idle for x amount of seconds.  For some reason the script just returns the value 0.328 for idleTime instead of actually counting the seconds ive been idle.  Not really sure where this problem lies so here is my code

```
import os
import datetime
from ctypes import Structure, windll, c_uint, sizeof, byref

#Script will automatically restart computer at 4 am unless user 
#hits abort button.

os.system("start C:/Users/alexa/Desktop/test.txt")

#checks how long user has been idle for
class LASTINPUTINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ('cbSize', c_uint),
    ('dwTime', c_uint),
]

def get_idle_duration():
    lastInputInfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = sizeof(lastInputInfo)
    windll.user32.GetLastInputInfo(byref(lastInputInfo))
    millis = windll.kernel32.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime
    return millis / 1000.0


idleTime = get_idle_duration()

while(idleTime <= 30):
    print(idleTime)
    if(idleTime >= 30):
        os.system("shutdown")
```

Answer (score 2):

You never update `idleTime` you set it once and then execute a while loop....

Answer (score 1):

As said by Pythonista, you are not updating python time, but since I cant yet post comment I am including solution as new answer

```
while(True):
    idleTime = get_idle_duration()
    print(idleTime)
    if(idleTime >= 30):
        os.system("shutdown")
```

However to consume resources it is good idea to import time and add

```
time.sleep(1)
```

at the end of while loop so it only checks once a second...

Answer (score 0):

Pythonista is correct. Also you are returning millis variable divided by 1000. This will make your execution of restart very lengthy because it will take 1000x's longer then the set duration to restart. I suggest you test this program without the division in the return and try something around 5 minutes and see what you get as a result.